# Adding columns with a Map Function Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that takes in a series and returns a dataframe, as so:

```
def check_streak(x):

    streak = x.to_frame(name = x.name)
    
    streak[f'start_of_streak'] = streak[x.name].ne(streak[x.name].shift())
    streak[f'{x.name}_streak_count'] = streak['start_of_streak'].cumsum()
    
    
    return streak
```

I'd like to map it over all the columns in a dataframe I have so that each column would now have three columns in its place:

When I try this:

```
stack_example = pivot.apply(check_streak, axis='columns', result_type='expand')
```

I get an error: what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Example Data

```
            col_1   col_2
2022-01-01   1      0
2022-02-01   1      1
2022-03-01   1      0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use `apply` on several columns, your function should return a `Series`.

You might want to use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([check_streak(pivot[col]) for col in pivot], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
            col_1  start_of_streak  col_1_streak_count  col_2  start_of_streak  col_2_streak_count
2022-01-01      1             True                   1      0             True                   1
2022-02-01      1            False                   1      1             True                   2
2022-03-01      1            False                   1      0             True                   3
```

Comment: Ah thank-you! This works but it doesn't seem like best practise so I suppose you're not 'meant' to use a function like this - what would be the 'correct' way to do this task?